# write() creates empty file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I want to write to a file but if I open as `open(file,"w")` it outputs a blank file, it does work with `open(file,"a")` but I don't want to append since it gets really large really fast and I just need to update the file.

This is the code:

```
p1 = open("C:\\Users\\JoãoPedro\\Documents\\Python\\PrimeFactoring\\primes1.txt","r")
Prime_list = p1.read()
Prime_list = Prime_list.split()
p1.close()

L_List = len(Prime_list)
i = 29420
x = [Here goes a really large number]
while (i <= L_List):
   Primorial_List = open("Primorial.txt","w")
   Primorial_List.write("%d :: %s :: %d \n"%(i,Prime_list[i],x))
   Primorial_List.close()
   print(str(i) + " :: " + Prime_list[i])

   i += 1
   x = x * int(Prime_list[i])

print("Finished")
```

On the code the indentation is right but I don't know why I can't indent the code here :/

One thing I noticed is that I'm not running the idle as administrator should I do that?

Comment: Don't repost your question, edit the original question. If it's better, the question will be reopene.

Comment: possible duplicate of [write() in python doesn't do anything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352514/write-in-python-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: The only difference between opening with `w` or `a` mode is whether it truncates the file first. The `write()` calls should be the same.

Comment: Use the `{}` tool in the SO editor to mark your code as literal, so the indentation will be kept.

Comment: Are you really reopening the file each time through the loop? That will overwrite whatever was written for the previous elements of `L_List`. The file will only contain the result from the last element of the list.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's what I think is weird, because when I run it works fine with "a" but not with "w"

Comment: I just need to update it with the new value of x the rest is unimportant and if I keep it gets really large really fast

Comment: You shouldn't open and write the file in a loop--it's wasteful.  Compute  your result and write it once, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
while (i <= L_List):
   Primorial_List = open("Primorial.txt","w")
   Primorial_List.write("%d :: %s :: %d \n"%(i,Prime_list[i],x))
   Primorial_List.close()
   print(str(i) + " :: " + Prime_list[i])

   i += 1
   x = x * int(Prime_list[i])
```

what happens if you do something like:

```
for i in range(MAGIC_NUMBER, len(L_List)+1):
    print(str(i) + " :: " + Prime_list[i])
    x *= int(Prime_list[i])
with open("Primorial.txt", "w") as Primorial_List:
    l = len(L_List)
    Primorial_List.write("%d :: %s :: %d \n"%(l,Prime_list[l],x))
```

As @Barmar mentioned - the way you currently have it's overwriting the file every time (as you want), and as @John Zwinck mentioned, that's very wasteful - stay in Python as long as you can (doing all your computation) and only once you're at the end of your list, write it, just the once.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help but it's not helping with my main question in the first place, why doesn't it write at all, like it just creates a blank file

Answer (score 0):

```
Primorial_List = open("Primorial.txt","w")
while (i <= L_List):
    Primorial_List.write("%d :: %s :: %d \n"%(i,Prime_list[i],x))
    Primorial_List.close()
    print(str(i) + " :: " + Prime_list[i])
    i += 1
    x = x * int(Prime_list[i])
Primorial_List.close()
```

Reformatting the code to open the file before the loop and closing on completion had it working and creating a file containing the data.

Comment: Removing the Primorial_List.close() statement within the while should help :-)

Comment: Yes, Thank you thiruvenkadam!  Sorry was having problems with cutting and pasting operations :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should have given your IndexError for sure at the end of the while because of these

```
i += 1
x = x * int(Prime_list[i])
```

Not to mention there is a

```
while (i <= L_List):
```

which will allow one more iteration that will lead to IndexError with the Primorial_List.write as well. If your code ran properly, you should check for any try... except used that would call this block of code. There you might find the reason for emptying your file. Somewhere, you might just open the file and close the file after this block of code? Or a logical equivalent of something like this might be the reason:

```
while (i <= L_List):

    Primorial_List = open("Primorial.txt","w")
    try:
        Primorial_List.write("%d :: %s :: %d \n"%(i,Prime_list[i],x))
    except:
        pass
    Primorial_List.close()
```

Or something like this:

```
try:
    while (i <= L_List):
        Primorial_List = open("Primorial.txt","w")
        Primorial_List.write("%d :: %s :: %d \n"%(i,Prime_list[i],x))
        Primorial_List.close()
except:
    pass
```

which would means that the code would move from Primorial_List.write method to except as it will cause IndexError for the last iteration because of Prime_list[i].

In case there are no try... except blocks, then I would assume that you would have pushed the i+=1 statement next to x = x * Prime_list[i] which will also make the file empty but ends with a IndexError at the end nonetheless.

On a side note, as others mentioned, you should open the file once and write once rather than writing it continuously. Better yet, make use of the [with](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement of Python for file operations. Following might be the equivalent :-)

```
with open("C:\\Users\\JoãoPedro\\Documents\\Python\\PrimeFactoring\\primes1.txt") as fo:
    Prime_list = fo.read()

Prime_list = Prime_list.split()
L_List = len(Prime_list)
i = 29420
x = [Here goes a really large number]

new_file_content = ""
while (i < L_List):
   new_file_content += "%d :: %s :: %d \n"%(i,Prime_list[i],x)
   print(str(i) + " :: " + Prime_list[i])
   x = x * int(Prime_list[i])
   i += 1

with open("Primorial.txt", "w") as fo:
    fo.write(new_file_content)

print("Finished")
```